# Why can't my friends see my posts on timeline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

Today I was checking the "view as" feature of Facebook and noticed that two of my friends can't see my posts and the pics that I have uploaded on my timeline. I mean it was showing nothing,not even a single post that I posted on my timeline.

This problem is coming with only two of my friends. How could this be corrected?